# ssh -X not setting $DISPLAY

Tags: linux, ssh, xorg, login

#### TL;DR

OS: RHEL 7.x

`ssh -X` works on some hosts, not on others. `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` is the same.
This used to work on our old software release, it does not on the new release. Cannot find anything that has changed. 
 **What else am I missing?**

**UPDATE** 14-May
In our TEst environment, port 6000 is blocked. In our Development environment, port 6000 is *not* blocked. We are not running firewalld nor iptables. Adding allow port 6000 to the default iptables config file makes the remote display work. Other than a firewall, where else would this be blocked?

If I set `X11UseLocalHost` to no, everything works. But, none of my other hosts have this value set. (Isn't NO the default?)
Grrr. So frustrated.

What stupid hidden thing am I missing?

---

#### Details

```
ScottieH:$ xhost
access control enabled, only authorized hosts can connect
ScottieH:$ echo $DISPLAY
:0.0
```

```
ScottieH:$ ssh -X host_007
host_007:$ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0
host_007:$ cat /etc/redhat-release
RHEL Workstation 7.6
host_007:$ xlogo
host_007:$        # xlogo displays on host ScottieH
host_007:$ logout
```

```
ScottieH:$ ssh -X NF_013
NF_201:$ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0
NF_201:$ cat /etc/redhat_release
RHEL Server 7.6
NF_201:$ xlogo
NF_201:$        # xlogo displays on host ScottieH
NF_201:$ logout
```

```
ScottieH:$ ssh -X SS_004
SS_004:$ echo $DISPLAY
DISPLAY: Undefined variable.
SS_004:$ cat /etc/redhat_release
RHEL Server 7.6
SS_004:$ logout
```

```
ScottieH:$ sdiff -s [NF_001:/etc/ssh/sshd_config] [SS_004:/etc/ssh/sshd_config]
ScottieH:$        # no differences found
```

```
ScottieH:$ ssh -X SS_004
SS_004:$ echo "X11UseLocalHost no" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
SS_004:$ sudo systemctl restart sshd
SS_004:$ logout
ScottieH:$ ssh -X SS_004
SS_004:$ echo $DISPLAY
<ip_address_of_server>:10.0
SS_004:$ xlogo
SS_004:$        # xlogo displays on host ScottieH
SS_004:$ logout
```

Note: `NF_013` is a cluster, `SS_004` is also a cluster.

```
     NF_013 ==:== DNS Entry x.y.z.1
           |
NF_201 ----+---- BK_001
x.y.z.3          x.y.z.10


     SS_004 ==:== DNS Entry x.q.z.6 --> This is the IP address that shows in the DISPLAY variable
           |
SA_004 ----+---- SB_004
x.q.z.5          x.y.z.98
```

Comment: you need to check the output of `ssh -v -X SS_004`

Comment: Is `DISPLAY: Undefined variable` a literal text you get? Usually shells expand unset variables to empty strings. I can do `set -u` but shells I tested use different error message then. This brings up a question: what shells did you use? SSH server spawns a login shell on the remote side, such shell sources some files. Maybe there is (conditional?) `unset DISPLAY` in one of them or some shenanigan happens.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yes. `DISPLAY: Undefined variable` is literally what I get. We use csh, tcsh, sh, bash, ksh and zsh for our shells.

Comment: @EchoMike444 Ran `ssh -v` tracked the error. It said to set `X11 UseLocalHost no`, which is the default.